# Plotly: How to make grouped bargraphs on top of each other?

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart, overlay, group

This is a plotly question as I wish to have the interactive graph.
I am trying to make two sets of grouped bargraphs on top of each other in which one of the sets is not filled but with a thick line and the other set is filled.

This is my dummy dataset:

```
from numpy import random
import pandas as pd

list = []
for species in ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4']:
    for catalyst in ['CHA', 'SAPO', 'MOF','None']:
        for add in [True, False]:
            new_data = {'species': species, 
                        'catalyst': catalyst, 
                        'energy': random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0, size=None), 
                        'with_additive': add}
            list.append(new_data)
df = pd.DataFrame(list)            
df
```

Next, in plotly I manage to make bargraphs one over the other like this

```
fig = px.bar(df,
             x='species',
             y='energy',
             facet_row ='with_additive',
             color = 'catalyst',
             barmode ='group',
             pattern_shape="with_additive", pattern_shape_sequence=[".", ""]
            )
fig
```

with this result:
[image: plotly bragraphs, two separate graphs]

I can also make them in the same plot, but then the two sets end up side by side as in the following:

```
fig = px.bar(df,
             x='species',
             y='energy',
             #facet_row ='with_additive',
             color = 'catalyst',
             barmode ='group',
             pattern_shape="with_additive", pattern_shape_sequence=[".", ""]
            )
fig
```

Producing this:
[image: All in one graph side by side]

Then I tried to add the second set as a trace, but do not mange to make that grouped:

```
fig = px.bar(df[df.with_additive==True],
             x='species',
             y='energy',
             #facet_row ='with_additive',
             color = 'catalyst',
             barmode ='group',

            )

fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(x=df[df.with_additive==True].species, y=df[df.with_additive==True].energy,
           #color = 'surface',
           alignmentgroup ='species',
           base='overlay',
        )
    )
```

[image: Add a second trace, not grouped correctly]

So, what I am missing is: How to get one of the sets with black line contour, and get how to the two sets perfetcly ontop of each other as in the followig matplotlib examples:

```
df_pivot1 = pd.pivot_table(
   df[df.with_additive==True],
   values="energy",
   index="catalyst",
   columns="species",
)

df_pivot2 = pd.pivot_table(
   df[df.with_additive==False],
   values="energy",
   index="catalyst",
   columns="species",
)

 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,5)) 
df_pivot1.plot(kind="bar", ax=ax)
df_pivot2.plot(kind="bar", edgecolor='black', linewidth=2, ax=ax, fill=False)

handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
handle_list =handles[0:5]
label_list= labels[0:4]
label_list.append('no additive')
plt.legend(handle_list, label_list, loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.1), ncol=5)
```

[image: As desired, but with matplotlib]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

**1.** Build two figures `fig1=px.bar()` and `fig2=px.bar()`

**2.** Make the necessary changes to `fig2` to make the traces stand out with no color and a black line with:

```
 fig2.update_traces(marker_color = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)', marker_line_color = 'black')
```

**3.** Change the trace names of `fig2` with:

```
fig2.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(name = t.name + ' No additives'))
```

**3.** Set up a new figure `fig=go.Figure(fig1.data)`

**4.** Add the edited traces to `fig` from `fig2` using `fig.add_traces(fig2.data)`

And that's it:

#### Plot

[image]

#### Code:

```
from numpy import random
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

list = []
for species in ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4']:
    for catalyst in ['CHA', 'SAPO', 'MOF','None']:
        for add in [True, False]:
            new_data = {'species': species, 
                        'catalyst': catalyst, 
                        'energy': random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0, size=None), 
                        'with_additive': add}
            list.append(new_data)
df = pd.DataFrame(list)            

fig1 = px.bar(df[df.with_additive==True],
             x='species',
             y='energy',
             facet_row ='with_additive',
             color = 'catalyst',
             barmode ='group',
             # pattern_shape="with_additive", pattern_shape_sequence=[".", ""]
            )

fig2 = px.bar(df[df.with_additive==False],
             x='species',
             y='energy',
             facet_row ='with_additive',
             color = 'catalyst',
             barmode ='group',
            )

fig2.update_traces(marker_color = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)', marker_line_color = 'black')
fig2.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(name = t.name + ' No addititves'))

fig = go.Figure(fig1.data)
fig.add_traces(fig2.data)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanx a lot! This was exaclt what I needed

Comment: @francescab You're welcome! And thank you for accepting my answer. If my suggestion was useful, upvotes are always welcome.